# SQL - Displaying Queries

Tags: sql, oracle, csv, oracle-sqldeveloper

Currently I'm testing some queries and this query below

```
select DISTINCT GENRES
FROM GENRES ;
```

Displays:

```
  Genres
0 Action,Adventure,Romance
1 Drama
```

How would I write it so it would show the output in the format below?

```
  Genres
1 Action
2 Adventure
3 Romance
4 Drama
```

Any help would be useful! Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way to split a csv string with regexes and a recursive query:

```
select distinct trim(regexp_substr(genre, '[^,]+', 1, level)) genre
from mytable
connect by instr(genre, ',', 1, level - 1) > 0
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=88175f387290952b1d3d826b548162e2)**:

```
with mytable as (
    select 'Action,Adventure,Romance' genre from dual
    union all select 'Drama' from dual
)
select distinct trim(regexp_substr(genre, '[^,]+', 1, level)) genre
from mytable
connect by instr(genre, ',', 1, level - 1) > 0
```

```
| GENRE     |
| :-------- |
| Action    |
| Adventure |
| Romance   |
| Drama     |
```

Comment: This works but say if more genres are entered later, then this code will need amending again right?

Comment: @SulaymanKhan: this is a recursive query, so it is dynamic. It extracts all the genres from the delimited string, no matter how many there are.

Answer (score 0):

```
SQL> with genres (id, genres) as
  2    (select 0, 'Action,Adventure,Romance' from dual union all
  3     select 1, 'Drama' from dual
  4    )
  5  select rownum id,
  6    regexp_substr(genres, '[^,]+', 1, column_value) genres
  7  from genres cross join
  8       table(cast(multiset(select level from dual
  9                           connect by level <= regexp_count(genres, ',') + 1
 10                          ) as sys.odcinumberlist));

        ID GENRES
---------- --------------------
         1 Action
         2 Adventure
         3 Romance
         4 Drama

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

"this works but say if more genres are entered later".  In spite of a working solution, your data model itself if fundamentally flawed.  It violates First Normal Form.  Also, it is very confusing to have a table and a column with the same name (GENRES).  You should have 3 tables to model this data:

```
SQL> CREATE TABLE MOVIES
  2     (MOVIE_ID NUMBER NOT NULL ENABLE,
  3      TITLE VARCHAR2(20 BYTE) NOT NULL ENABLE,
  4      DIRECTOR VARCHAR2(20 BYTE) NOT NULL ENABLE,
  5           CONSTRAINT MOVIES_PK PRIMARY KEY (MOVIE_ID)
  6     );

Table created.

SQL>
SQL> CREATE TABLE MOVIE_GENRES
  2     (GENRE_ID NUMBER NOT NULL ENABLE,
  3      GENRE_NAME VARCHAR2(20 BYTE),
  4           CONSTRAINT MOVIE_GENRES_PK PRIMARY KEY (GENRE_ID)
  5     );

Table created.

SQL>
SQL> CREATE TABLE LK_MOVIES_GENRES
  2     (LK_MOVIES_GENRES_ID NUMBER NOT NULL ENABLE,
  3      MOVIE_ID NUMBER NOT NULL ENABLE,
  4      GENRE_ID NUMBER NOT NULL ENABLE,
  5           CONSTRAINT LK_MOVIES_GENRES_PK PRIMARY KEY (MOVIE_ID),
  6           CONSTRAINT FK_MOVIES FOREIGN KEY (MOVIE_ID)
  7            REFERENCES MOVIES (MOVIE_ID) ENABLE,
  8           CONSTRAINT FK_GENRES FOREIGN KEY (GENRE_ID)
  9            REFERENCES MOVIE_GENRES (GENRE_ID) ENABLE
 10     );

Table created.
```

Comment: Yeah I have a movie table also which i did not show, my plan was to add another column called MOVIE_ID to show the genres that go with that movie ID.